# How to get CFS Bandwidth control linux patch?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, patch

I am looking to use CFS bandwidth capability to set a hardlimit of the cpu usage of a process (http://lwn.net/Articles/452584/). I can see they have a patch for the existing kernel which can enable this option. But I have no idea where to get this patch . Can someone help me understand how to use such patches in linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps some general clarifications first - despite the use of source control, many kernel hackers still prefer the old way of posting patches on the mailing list and perform peer review through the association of a list of patches with a public mailing thread. In the convention that was created prior to git, a person who works on a new feature separates the work into a series of patches (which might have dependencies). Each patch is posted in a different message. By convention, the E-Mail that is announcing the series of patches is prefixed with [00/, which is why you don't see any patches in the first E-Mail. Unfortunately, this approach is not very clear to the newbies.

There are several, rather old documentation that tells how to work with patches in E-Mail. Note that the patch is not a standard MIME-attachment, but just a concatenation of text into a plain-text E-Mail.

The lkml.org link to the post that announces 'CFS Bandwidth Control v7.2' is [here](https://lkml.org/lkml/2011/7/21/407). From there, you have access to each of the 18 parts of the patch, each in a separate E-Mail in that thread. You can use 'Get diff' that appears on the left side below the thread in order to download each of the 18 diffs.

In order to apply the patches that you download, please read [about working with patches](http://www.linuxchix.org/content/courses/kernel_hacking/lesson9).